# BroadcastReceiever Not Getting Called

Tags: java, android, http

I've been trying to have my class `BatteryPost` be called by an alarmmanager in my onCreate method:

BatteryPost.java:

```
public class BatteryPost extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String batteryText = prefs.getString("battery", null);
    String id = prefs.getString("id", null);
    String URL = "http://mysite.com/checkin/index.php?device_uid="+id+"&bat="+batteryText; 
    {
    try{
    String uri = URL.replace(" ", "%20"); //replace spaces with %20
    Log.d("Checkin", uri);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri); //post object
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //execution
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("Checkin", "ClientProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException i) {
        Log.d("Checkin", "IOException");
    }
   }

 }
}
```

Which should be getting hit by the AlarmManager in my onCreate():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*
         * Our onCreate block...
         */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        Context context = getApplicationContext();  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submit.setOnClickListener(submitListener); //Initialization of the view and objects
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BatteryPost.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 600000, sender);

}
```

When I hit the button I registered to manually update the battery level to the server it works, so the values are being stored properly, but the AlarmManager fails to call BatteryPost every minute (just every minute for testing, will be longer after).

I've been looking at other posts on SO to try and find similar code, but implementing this has become tricky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you have it checking ever `600000` milliseconds. This is not  60 seconds, but 600, or in other words, 10 minutes. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Just was missing one thing, works now, but I would've overlooked this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes.